# Python Dictionary Username Password P

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, passwords

I'm trying to create a python username and password database (just for practice) with the dictionary function. So far, I have written this much of the code.

```
username_password = {"Dave":"manchester"}
print("Sign up for NetFlour!\n")
name = str(input("Please enter your preferred username.\n"))
passcode = str(input("Thank you, now enter a password as well.\n"))
username_password[name] = passcode
print(username_password)
```

I have simply called the software 'Netflour' and have stored the input from the user and the corresponding password into the dictionary named username_password. Here, only one user has signed up for the service, who is Dave. He has assigned a password called 'Manchester.' 

**Now**, i'm going to write code for which the user enters their username and password and 'logs' in to their profile. My question is, how do I do that? I have tried has_key but i'm in python 3.3, and they had removed this function previously. My next line of code would be -

```
login_username = str(input("Please enter your username.\n"))
login_password = str(input("Please enter your password.\n"))
```

Here, i would create an if - else statement, where if the username and password match, they are taken to their homescreen, else if it is incorrect, they must re - enter both pieces of information. I have been suggested to use the 'in' function, but since I'm not SO advanced in python, I require some assistance. At this moment, I'm not so interested in encryption, but I will be advancing to that stage once I have written the if - else code which gets Python to check simultaneously if the username and password is correct. 
 Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do `str(input())` in python3. `input()` itself returns a string representation.

Answer (score 3):

```
if username_password.get(login_username) == login_password:
    # Correct username and password match
    pass
else:
    # Incorrect username/password match
    pass
```

The `get` method of a python dictionary takes the key as its argument and returns the value if it exists. If the key/value pair does not exist, `get` returns `None`.

---

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for more details. From the link:

### **get**(*key[, default]*)

> Return the value for key if *key* is in the dictionary, else *default*. If
>   *default* is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never
>   raises a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# strip any whitespace from the ends of the input
login_username, login_password = login_username.strip(), login_password.strip()

# check username and password entered are correct
if login_username in username_password and login_password == username_password[login_username]:
    print("Logged in")
else:
    print("bad username / password")
```

Comment: Nice try, though you are accessing the dictionary twice. That isn't required, you can use the builtin `dict.get(key, DefaultReturn)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'Dave':'secretpassword'}
login_username='Dave'
login_password='abc'
if d.has_key(login_username):
    if d[login_username]==login_password:
        print('username and password match')
    else:
        print('user entered the wrong password')
else:
    print('your username is not registered. Would you like to register')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if login_username in username_passwords.keys() 
        and login_password == username_password[login_username]:
    print "Logged on"
else
    print "Wrong credentials"
```

Answer (score 0):

0down vote

if login_username in username_passwords.keys() 
        and login_password == username_password[login_username]:
    print "Logged on"
else
    print "Wrong credentials"  LOL NO